# is there any lib to simulate user click like casperjs at greasemonkey?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, casperjs

I'm going to write a userscript to simulate user click.

I'm using `jquery.trigger`, but I wonder is there any 3rd lib that can save me like CasperJS.

so I can use something like :

```
this.fill('form#contact-form', {
    'subject':    'I am watching you',
    'content':    'So be careful.',
    'civility':   'Mr',
    'name':       'Chuck Norris',
    'email':      'chuck@norris.com',
    'cc':         true,
    'attachment': '/Users/chuck/roundhousekick.doc'
}, true);

this.click('h3.r a');
```

Answer (score 3):

CasperJS ships with client side utils you can use in a normal browser page: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html; it exposes the `fill()` method as well as many others.

You can even inject it using the provided bookmarklet to play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are pretty mush of such solutions. On of the most famous is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs)

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524697/1888017)

Comment: I know these testing tool, but I'm search for some js lib that can use at greasemonkey userscript

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to explain better. the `Event.simulate` do the same thing as jquery.trigger. But I want a full solution to simulation, or I just want to got a greasemonkey version of capserjs, which provide utils like click,wait,fill etc.

Comment: Think you need to code your own, place it on github and send me the link, end I will extend my answer with such a nice lib =_)